# how to concatinate a string to a $scope model in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, angularjs-forms

How can I concatenate a variable to the `$scope` model. I am trying to do something like this

```
for(var i=0;i<=response.length-1;i++)
{
   $scope.formData.jobId+i=response[i].jobId;
}
```

How can I concatenate  the variable `i` to `$scope.formData.jobId` so that it becomes `$scope.formData.jobId1`, `$scope.formData.jobId2` and so one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it like this by dynamically constructing your property name and using it as a string

```
$scope.formData['jobId' + i] = response[i].jobId;
```